# Does the weekly heroic strike save your progress if you leave it?

Tags: destiny

If you leave the weekly heroic in the middle of it will you be able to come back to it before the weekly reset?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do the mission again but you will have to **start over from the beginning**.

As far as I know the only mid mission saves are Story missions and Raids.

It is also worth bearing in mind that you can only earn each difficulty tier reward once per week.

Comment: Worth noting that "each difficulty tier rewards" are inclusive, 30-level weekly includes the rewards for lower levels (and their once-per-week status as well).

Answer (score 1):

The weekly heroic strike will not save your progress if you leave at any point. However, uncomplete or complete, you may do the strike as many times as you wish.

You will only get the listed rewards the first time you complete the strike (if you complete it at a lower level, and attempt a higher level later you will see an updated set of rewards which are still available). Leaving early does not affect the rewards.

Answer (score 0):

No, leaving a Story and a Strike Requires you to do it over.  There is no Mid Level save.  If there is one for Raids, then I do not know about that.  Only dieing allows you to spawn at a checkpoint previous to each encounter.

Comment: Story missions do have checkpoints.

Comment: But not save points like what OP was asking for.

Comment: Story missions do have save points OP was asking for as well.

Comment: Where did you get this information? The only true thing you said is that strikes require you start from the beginning if you leave.

Comment: I play Destiny.  So all my answers come from that.